# Python: search all lines, which contain "word"

Tags: python

I have trouble with text parsing.

Title: via Grab lib I GET html page, after that I convert it via NLTK lib in text, and put this text in variable. After this, I want search all lines, which contain "word", and print this line.

For example we have next text:

test1: olololo
test2: print something
FAQ it's Frequently Asked Question(s)
I want search `test1`, and print result as: `test1: olololo`

```
import logging, nltk
from grab import Grab
from urllib import urlopen

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
parsing_url = raw_input("Enter URL:")
if parsing_url.startswith('http://') or parsing_url.startswith('https://'):
    parsing_url = parsing_url.replace('http://','').replace('https://','')
print parsing_url
g = Grab()
g.go('http://user:pass@' + parsing_url, log_file='out.html')
url = "out.html"
html = urlopen(url).read()
raw = nltk.clean_html(html)
```

In bash I realized it like:

```
root@srv:~$ cat 123 | grep "test1"
```

And as result I get:

```
test1: olololo
```

But in Python I don't want execute bash commands :)

Comment: Have you gave a try to my answer? I'd be glad to improve it if something is wrong.

Comment: yep, i'm try your method, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
for line in html.split():
  if "test1" in line:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `raw` is a list of strings (i.e. list of lines):

```
good_lines = [l for l in raw if 'test1' in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe someone might find it useful, i solve this problem like this:
1. decode html to text using NLTK lib
2. record this text to file
3. parsing file via bash command. for example:

```
status,host = commands.getstatusoutput("cat raw.log | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | grep -A 2 \"On Host\" | sed -n 2p")
```

Also, I'm trying to parse this text using the tools python